# Can't Access Properties Off of Struct In Foundry / Forge: Possibly Due to Nested Mapping

Tags: solidity, testing, struct, foundry, forge

I am unable to get attributes off a struct in my contract from my Foundry test file. How can I get a property off an instance of a struct in my contract from my Foundry test file.

In `DAO.sol` contract (outside of contract):

```
struct Proposal {
    uint256 id;
    
    address proposer;

    ...
    mapping(address => Receipt) receipts;

}

...

struct Receipt {
    /// @notice Whether or not a vote has been cast
    bool hasVoted;
    /// @notice Whether or not the voter supports the proposal
    bool support;
    /// @notice The number of votes the voter had, which were cast
    uint96 votes;
}

...

mapping(uint256 => Proposal) public proposals;
...
```

In test contract `DAO.t.sol`:

```
address proposer = dao.proposals(proposalId).proposer;
```

Is resulting in this error:

```
Error:
Compiler run failed
error[9582]: TypeError: Member "proposer" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in tuple(uint256,address,uint256,uint256,uint256,bool,bool).
  --> test/DAO.t.sol:94:28:
   |
94 |         address proposer = dao.proposals(proposalId).proposer;
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

When I try the following, instead:

```
Proposal storage proposal = Proposal(dao.proposals(proposalId));
```

I get this error:

```
Error:
Compiler run failed
error[9515]: TypeError: Struct containing a (nested) mapping cannot be constructed.
  --> test/DAO.t.sol:98:37:
   |
98 |         Proposal storage proposal = Proposal(dao.proposals(proposalId));
   |                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

propose function in DAO contract:

```
function propose(
    address[] memory targets,
    uint256[] memory values,
    string[] memory signatures,
    bytes[] memory calldatas,
    string memory description
) public onlyMembers returns (uint256) {

    ...

    proposalCount++;
    uint256 newProposalId = proposalCount;
    Proposal storage newProposal = proposals[newProposalId];

    newProposal.id = newProposalId;
    newProposal.proposer = msg.sender;
    ...

    emit ProposalCreated(
        newProposalId,
        msg.sender,
        ...
    );
    return newProposal.id;
}
```

Comment: have you found a solution my friend?